# SVG changing stroke after page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, stroke

When the page loads the JavaScript sets a stroke color.  After the color is set if the JavaScript changes that color it is not re-rendered by the browser.  Perhaps I am doing something wrong?
When the page loads this is executed

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mini-logo").attr('stroke', userSelectedColor);
});
```

Later the user can change the color and thus the stroke needs to change.

```
$("#mini-logo").attr('stroke', userSelectedColor);
```

Using Firebug the html has changed, but it has not been re-rendered.

Comment: how is `userSelectedColor` inferred?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] as a stack snippet or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you setting styles in addition to setting attributes? Style settings take precedence over attribute setting. For example, if you set the initial stroke color using both style in CSS file and attribute in JS file then later changes to attribute in JS file would have no visual effect.